# jquery .each function and passing variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to loop through a set of `<a>`'s in an unordered list.

In jQuery, I'd do it this way:

```
$("#list ul li a").each(function (x) {
 // Do Stuff
});
```

It's probably a simple question, but how do I pass a variable through as that `id` shown in the function there?  I'd imagine it is something like:

```
  var myVar = 'foo';
   $("#list ul li a").each(myVar, function (x) {
     // Do Stuff
     console.log(x);
    });
```

Console out: `foo`.

But that doesnt seem to work, how do I do this?

Comment: $(this).attr('id'); will refer to the current element's id, so maybe this can be tha answer to your problem if i get your question correct.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "pass a variable through".  Code in the callback you pass to `.each()` can "see" local variables like "myVar" in the surrounding code. What is it that you want to do exactly?

Comment: @Pointy Can it really? I've had numerous times when .each and .ajax cannot see my local variables.

Comment: @Chud37 it depends on where they are declared. In your example, `console.log(myVar)` in the `each()` would work fine, though.

Comment: @Chud37 Take a look at this: [JavaScript Scope And Closures explained](http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/09/explaining-javascript-scope-and-closures/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to pass variable on `each(myVar, function(x)`. You can use `myVar` inside `each` with no problem.

```
var myVar = 'foo';
$("#list ul li a").each(function (x) {
   // Do Stuff
   console.log(x); // element index
   console.log(myVar); //foo
});
```

Let's see **what is wrong** with this code.

```
var myVar = 'foo';
$("#list ul li a").each(myVar, function (x) {
    // Do Stuff
    console.log(x);
});
```

You will get:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Because exects that first parameter to be a `function` and it's a variable.

Also `function(x)` will never be called because `each` take only 1 parameter.

Comment: Thanks, I think I misunderstood the variable scope.  This works, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Here is the solution,

just use "this" keyword like this:

```
        var myVar = 'foo';
        $("#list ul li a").each(function () {
           console.log($(this).attr('id'));
        });
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't think this answer is what the OP was looking for.

Comment: @TomerM this is not the answer I was looking for.

Comment: @Chud37 I were made adaptation to your needs.

Comment: @Chud37 myVar defined in function scope! you dont need to pass it.

Answer (score -4):

```
var myVar = 'foo';
   $("#list ul li a").each(myVar, function (id) {
     // Do Stuff
     console.log(id.attr("id"));
    });
```

Comment: `.each()` takes only one argument, and that argument must be a function.